# Line plot shows no line and Y axis has no labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build an RShiny app. Still pretty unexperienced with R but so far I've gotten this:

myData structure example

```
Customer Name | Customer ID |    Date    | Platform | Product | Input Records
Jimmy John's      JJ01        2020-08-17    Digital    FBR V2        15
Quiznos           QZ01        2020-08-15    Digital    FBR V2        30
Pizza Hut         PH01        2020-08-10    Digital    FBR V2        60
```

code for the DF, save into .txt

Customer Name   Customer ID Date    Platform    Product Input Records
Jimmy Johns JJ01    2020-08-17  Digital FBR V2  15000
Quiznos QZ01    2020-08-15  Digital FBR V2  20000
Pizza Hut   PH01    2020-08-10  Digital FBR V2  10000

And my code so far

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
myData<- read.table(file = "mydata.txt", header = TRUE, sep="\t")
myData$Date <- as.Date(myData$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
myPlot <- ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=Date, y="Input Records", group=1)) +
  geom_line()
```

But this is not generating anything
[image: Plout Output]

However, if I use a geom_col() type plot, with the `Platform` column, I do get an actual output, but still without any value labels in the Y axis.

[image]

Edit:
Thanks for the help, I managed to see the error and use `Input.Records` instead to specify column name.
However, the rendered plot does not seem to be correct at all. It's supposed to be a line plot, but its looking more like a hollowed out column. [image]

Comment: please provide the example code to generate the dataframe

Comment: OK, I just did, simply copy and paste into a .txt file

Answer (score 0):

`aes` expects the variables/symbols and not the names (and using quotation marks gives the string/name). To correctly address a variable with a forbidden name, you need to use backticks `` (` `) ``, so it's `` `Input Records` ``.

```r
myData <- data.frame(
  `Customer Name` = c("Jimmy John's", "Quiznos", "Pizza Hut"),
  `Customer ID` = c("JJ01", "QZ01", "PH01"),
  Date = c("2020-08-17", "2020-08-15", "2020-08-10"),
  Platform = rep("Digital", 3),
  Product = rep("FBR V2", 3),
  `Input Records` = c(15, 30, 60)
)
colnames(myData) <- c("Customer Name", "Customer ID", "Date",
                      "Platform", "Product", "Input Records")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

myData$Date <- as.Date(myData$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
myPlot <- ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=Date, y=`Input Records`, group=1)) +
  geom_line()
myPlot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I used the backticks for `Input Records` but I got "object Input Records not found".
I didnt use the initial code to manually create the DF, since I'm already loading a txt with it.

Furthermore, the scale seems messed up, it's not actually plotting a linear trajectory, it seems like hollow columns. will add it to the post.\

Comment: Then you should check your actual column names with `colnames(myData)`

Comment: It seems R by default removes the space between words in a column name with a .